# Change pagination link in yii\grid\GridView

Tags: gridview, yii, pagination, yii2, pjax

I'm using GridView with Pjax in my view file in my Yii2 project like this:

```
<?php
Pjax::begin();
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'person.name',
        'person.email',
        'person.dob',
    ],
]);
Pjax::end();
?>
```

I need to redirect user to different URL when pagination.

How do I change pagination links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `route` option for the `pagination` object used when calling the `ActiveDataProvider` in the search model's `search()` function

Use the `route` property in the following way and change accordingly in the `search()` function

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 5,
        'route' => 'controller/action'
    ]
]);
```